# Using @Service in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I do project using Spring MVC and so far I didn't use the @Service. I do all reading, saving, searching from database in my Controllers but I wan't introduce the Services.

Can somebody show me basics example of using @Service ? I read about Services but the 'logic buisness'  doesn't told me to much HOW it exactly works.

I know about how @Entity and @Controller works.

Can somebody write some examples which can help me to understand how it works ?

For example I want write Service which read elements from database, sorting them and give to Controller list of sorted elements.